# Technique for beating the Ice Titan in the Trial time limit

Tags: castlevania-lords-of-shadow

I've already beaten the Ice Titan at the end of Chapter 1, but for his stage's Trial, you need to beat him in under one minute, thirty seconds.

So far I haven't been able to do it.

What are some techniques to beat him under the time limit?

Note: The game's full name is Castlevania: Lords of Shadow, but that is too long for the tag system.

Comment: It has occurred to me that I may have to complete other parts of the game to get other powerups to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommended that you end the game before start with the trials, since there is a sub-weapon that will help you in the time trials.

> Use the dark crystal in order to reduce its health bar dramatically.  From then on, every time you hit a weak spot once destroys it on contact. All you need is patience and practice.